# Using Shiny to insert records into a MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, r, datetime, shiny

I wish to write back to a mysql database based on a shiny app.
This code with some modifications come from the excellent [1](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html). I added a portion to give me the insertion timestamp of the record. When i try to insert the record i get the following error

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     could not run statement: Incorrect datetime value: '1473931679.54479' for column 'insert_dtm' at row 1

This datetime value is generated by `Add insertion time stamp of the record and re-order columns` of my code. Can anyone explain why this is happening.

I should mention in the table that is being written to the datatype is `DATETIME` but i can change this to anything as all im interested in is keeping track of when the records were inserted

```
save_data <- function(data) {
  # Connect to the database
  db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host =     
  options()$mysql$host, 
              port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
              password = options()$mysql$password)

  # Add insertion time stamp of the record and re-order columns
  data <- data %>% 
    mutate(insert_dtm =  Sys.time()) %>% 
    select (insert_dtm, everything()) %>% 

  # Construct the update query by looping over the data fields
  query <- sprintf(foo)

  # Submit the update query and disconnect
  dbGetQuery(db, query)
  dbDisconnect(db)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `as.Date(Sys.time(), format = "%Y-%m-%d")` instead of `Sys.time()`?

Comment: Thanks @GyD this is indeed the reason. I changed it in the MYSQL DB to update the timestamp when a new record comes into the system but also tested your solution which works. Thank you for your help. Please add it as an answer and i will accept it

Comment: I just realized you needed `datetime`, but I suggested converting to `date`,  but using the `format()` function (and converting to character) should work as well. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work is because of the difference between the date formats of `Sys.time()` and MySQL `date` or `datetime` types.

```
> Sys.time()
###[1] "2016-09-23 11:30:36 CEST"
###MySQL datetime: "2016-09-23 11:30:36"
```

After converting to MySQL datetime format it should work. I think the problem is the timezone.

For YYYY-MM-DD format

```
> format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d")
###[1] "2016-09-23"
```

For YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format

```
> format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
###[1] "2016-09-23 11:37:45"
```